# connecting to server and sending data to it in python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server address that I can connect to it through netcat. when I connect to the server through terminal the server gives me 3 random numbers each one is in it's own line. what I have to do is to multiply the first two numbers (first two lines) and divide them by the third number and I only have 0.1 seconds to do that (or more), so I have written a script which strip each line from the new line char and set it to a string then it will be converted to an integer so I can do the math and send the value I get to the server. So my code is this

```
import socket


adib = socket.socket()

host = 'services.cyberprotection.agency'

port = 9999


adib.connect((host, port))

naruto = adib.recv(1024)

if '\n' in naruto:
    line1, naruto = naruto.split('\n', 1)
    if '\n' in naruto:
        line2, naruto = naruto.split('\n', 1)
        if '\n' in naruto:
            line3, naruto = naruto.split('\n', 1)


akagami = int(line1) * int(line2) / int(line3)



print adib.sendall(str(akagami))




adib.close()
```

I don't know how to send the value of `akagami` or at least see the answer I get from sending the value, because I will get a flag after sending the value of `akagami`, I have tried `os.system` but connecting through terminal gives different values than connecting through socket so the value of the three numbers change each time a new connection is set. Also I can't conrol the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in 2.7 and 3.5:

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
addr, port = "services.cyberprotection.agency", 9999
s.connect((addr, port)) # create the connection
data = s.recv(1024) # this receives the 3 numbers
nums = list(map(int, data.split())) # convert from str/bytes to int
print(nums)
ans = nums[0] * nums[1] // nums[2] # double slash means integer division
s.sendall(b"%i" % ans) # send the answer. % formatting works for bytes in Python 3 where .format doesn't (for bytes)
print(ans) # print the answer you calculated
print(s.recv(1024).decode()) # print the one the server sends
```

Definitely not fault tolerant, but I hope it answers your question.

Example Output:

```
[65703, 26296, 60199]
28700
28700
```

I went ahead and put this in a loop. I simply appended the output to a list and ran it 500 times. My original plan was to note all of the outputs and see if it either repeats or if there is a formula that I could predict. That way, I could send an answer immediately after the request without calculating it. However, I ended up not even needing to. At some point, it responded quickly enough.

```
data = list(filter(lambda x: "flag" in x.lower(), data))
print(data)  # => ['The flag is: 917035HrQ0PODo#']
```

Comment: It only gives me the number that has been calculated, try to connect to the server and see how it functions

Comment: I did. I'll edit it with my output, but it prints the answer I calculated and the one I received from the server, which are equivalent.

Comment: The server should give me a flag when the right answer is entered quickly enough, I think it might be from the server side that it's not working but I am sure there is something like getting the values through socket library then input the answer through terminal. I mean you connect to the server through terminal then the script reads the threee values and calculate them then send them through terminal

Comment: I remember that there were something like `os.getcommandoutput` it might work but I am not sure about it's usage

Comment: yeah the server prints the correct answer after 0.1 seconds, so you should be fast enough to enter the answer before the server, and if you do it the server will return a flag value

Comment: I put it in a loop and actually got the flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105876/discussion-between-goodies-and-adib).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked out!, can you edit the script you wrote and implement the loop in it

Comment: You really should be able to do that on your own, but yes.